# Calling an Object Method on StartAtBootService from another class

Tags: java, android, service

I can't seem to understand why calling on method in ApolloMobileActivity in another class called StartAtBootService isn't working:

I have created a class called ApolloMobileActivity

```
public class ApolloMobileActivity extends Activity {
int j = 0;  

    public void callLog(){

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        setContentView(tv);

            tv.setText("Some Text");
     }
  }
```

Now in my StartAtBootService class I want to call the 'callLog()' method so,

```
 public class StartAtBootService extends Service
 {
private static final String TAG = "StartAtBootService";
ApolloMobileActivity callObject = new ApolloMobileActivity();

    //**This is where I am getting the error: Syntax error on token "callLog", Identifier expected after this token**
    callObject.callLog();

    //I am thinking that I can call this 'callObject' in onCreate to allow my service 
    //to run through my activity. I know I can use something like:
    //  Intent start = new Intent(context, ApolloMobileActivity.class);  
    //  start.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    //  context.startActivity(start);
    //But this will just start the Activity at boot in the foreground.
    //Is there some way to call this write this activity in on create so that it will show
    //in the background at boot-up?

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
                    //Some code here...
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is virtually nothing correct about the code you have here, assuming that `StartAtBootService` really is supposed to start at boot time.

Tactically, you cannot create an activity via its constructor, nor can you call `setContentView()` before `onCreate()` is called in the activity. Your service also is syntactically invalid, as you have a Java statement (`callObject.callLog();`) floating around outside a method.

Strategically, a service rarely should be starting an activity, and never at boot time.

> Is there some way to call this write this activity in on create so that it will show in the background at boot-up?

No, sorry.